# Query a dictionary to get top 3 most common elements

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

So I have an IEnumerable CallsForProperty  I need to find the top 3 question for specific time periods so I created 3 dictionaries

```
 Dictionary<int, string> FAQfor3Months = null;
 Dictionary<int, string> FAQfor4to12Months = null;
 Dictionary<int, string> FAQfor12plusMonths = null;

 foreach(Activity call in CallsForProperty){
   if( /*call is in 3 months*/ ){
      //do some unrelated stuff
      FAQfor3Months.Add(counter, call.callQuestion)
      counter++;
   }
 }
```

I have 2 questions,

I'm trying to grab the top 3 most frequent questions, is this query right?

```
var threeMonthFaqs = FAQfor3Months.GroupBy(x => x.Value).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).Take(3);
```

Also is this inefficient? Is there a better way to query the collection?

Comment: It's a little hard to discern what exactly you're trying to do here. There's also a number of additional questions this opens up; for example, if you have a backing data store, you'd generally want to try and do this query directly against the database instead of loading all the data into memory. Also, can you provide some comments on what exactly you want these dictionaries to hold? Are ou sure (in your approach) you don't want a Dictionary<string, int>, where the Key is the question, and Value is the number of times the question was asked?

Comment: What you are doing is definitely backwards from what you are asking. You don't need a `Dictionary` to store the questions, you can just use a `List<string>` and then query afterwards but it would be more efficient to reverse than `Dictionary` and increase the count as you encounter the questions (which is what a `GroupBy`+`Count` would essentially be doing later). Also initializing the variables to `null` won't allow you to use them.

Comment: Yeah I guess I tried to shorten it too much, The dictionary is being populated with a counter as an index and the string question as the value. I need the top 3 most asked questions in specific time frames so I was making a dictionary in each time frame.

Comment: @Neovssmith No, I see what your code is doing, it is just a bad way to accomplish what you want... the `Dictionary` is doing nothing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reversing the `Dictionary`s and counting each question as encountered, you can then use LINQ to pull out the top 3 questions:

```
var FAQfor3Months = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var FAQfor4to12Months = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var FAQfor12plusMonths = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (Activity call in CallsForProperty) {
    if ( /*call is in 3 months*/ ) {
        //do some unrelated stuff
        FAQfor3Months.TryGetValue(call.callQuestion, out int count);
        FAQfor3Months[call.callQuestion] = count+1;
    }
}

var top3ThreeMonthFaqs = FAQfor3Months.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value).Take(3).Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: I think I explained the question poorly/shortened and stackoverflow won't let me delete it. . There can be multiple questions that are the same so they can't be used as keys. I need to find how many times the question has been asked.

Comment: @Neovssmith But isn't that exactly why they should be used as keys? You want to combine the questions that are the same and count how many times they appear? Otherwise `GroupBy` wouldn't work...

Comment: Oh I think your right, I think this is a better way of doing it. Let me try to wire it up

Comment: @Neovssmith Note: You could be more efficient by using a special data structure that kept an index on the values and sorted only when added or changed, but unless you have tens of thousands of questions, it wouldn't be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will return the groups, not the actual questions.
Try this:

```
var threeMonthFaqs = FAQfor3Months.Values
                                  .GroupBy(q => q)
                                  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                                  .SelectMany(g => g)
                                  .Distinct()
                                  .Take(3);
```